# Get each element from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, each

I'm trying to make a small website checker and i'm trying to make it work with iframe so i can still get the CSS of each element. I looked time after time in this forum and on Google and i tried everything but for some reason it doesn't work for me..

This is the code i tried. I tried many variations, also Javascript but nothing worked..

```
document.domain = document.domain;

$("#mainFrame").contents().find("li").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

How can i get it to work please?
Thanks for any help

Comment: What does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: Could [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) get in the way?

Comment: @Donal, which is exactly what the questioner is doing.

Comment: will only work if iframe-content is from the same domain eg. the src attrivbute of the iframe

Comment: are you using this Script inside Ready function ?

Comment: The script is called after the iframe is loaded and the iframe content is on the same server but i do want it to work with other websites as well, same as website checkers.. How can i accomplish that?

Comment: The console shows- Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://checker.xcore.co.il" from accessing a frame with origin "http://xcore.co.il". Protocols, domains, and ports must match